# Trying to use MOBX in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx

I've read many tutorials about using mobx in React.
I'm trying to use implement it in React Native, with store logic but my results are not good and i'm not able to retrieve my global states from the store.

Here my app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from "react-native";

// import Search from './Components/Search';
import Navigation from './Navigation/Navigation';
import FilmStore from './Stores/FilmStore';


import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

@observer
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        // Empty 
        console.log(props.FilmStore);
       // empty
        console.log(FilmStore.test);
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
         <Navigation />
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer: { flex: 1 },
});
```

And here my mobx store

```
import { observable, computed, configure } from 'mobx';

// Strict mode
configure({
    enforceActions: 'always'
});

// Déclaration de notre store
class FilmStore {
    @observable test = 'aa';

    @computed setTest($text){
        this.test = $text;
    }
}

export default FilmStore;
```

As you can see props.FilmStore is empty. How I use mobx on react native could be wrong ?
Looking for help...

Thanks !

Comment: How do you pass `FilmStore` to `<App />`? The other way you try wont work as you expected, because you try to access the property on the Class instead of creating an instance and then access it.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not instantiating your store, I suspect you're also not instantiating when passing it as a prop. You can make one change on your store and use the singleton pattern to return a single instance of it, change

```
export default FilmStore;
```

to

```
export default new FilmStore();
```

Comment: You are right. I forgot many things. 
First I wasn't initializing the class like you said.
Then If i want to use my store in other view, I have to pass the store in the navigation component.

Thanks for help